# Visualize index entries in the text?

Tags: indexing, marginpar, text-decorations

When I ad an index entry using `\index` with all the [options available](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing) for the "format" and "see", and cross-reference, I'd like to see **at the place where I make the index entry** how this specific entry will/would appear in the index, i.e.

- Is it bold here?
- How is it sorted?
- Will the number be bold?
- Does it point elsewhere with "see"?

Currently I write the text in the margin with `\marginpar` but I am not quite satisfied with this. Maybe there is a better way that someone else already uses?

Comment: Related Question: [Mark indexed entries in the text itself?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/mark-indexed-entries-in-the-text-itself).

Comment: @PeterGrill Whow. Had I only known. I put my own tikz macro in place, doing exactly that.

Comment: Well, that is a new question. Perhaps you can post an answer using your `tikz` macros.

Answer (score 16):

You can automatize the generation of the marginal note:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeindex
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\@wrindex
  {\marginpar{\begingroup\catcode`\{=12\catcode`\}=12 \texttt{\scantokens{#1}}\endgroup}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

Thus each `\index` command will print in the margin the argument "as is". I believe this is better than trying to replicate the final aspect: all the information is there and in a very distinctive way.

The patching can be made depend on the `draft` option but not in a very robust way, as that option, in the standard classes, just sets `\overfullrule`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeindex
\makeatletter
\ifdim\overfullrule>\z@
  \pretocmd\@wrindex
    {\marginpar{\begingroup\catcode`\{=12\catcode`\}=12 \texttt{\scantokens{#1}}\endgroup}}
    {}{}
\fi
\makeatother
```

A more robust way might be to check if `draft` appears in the expansion of `\@classoptionslist` or putting the code inside a personal package, say `margind.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{margind}
\@tempswafalse
\DeclareOption{draft}{\@tempswatrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\if@tempswa
\pretocmd\@wrindex
  {\marginpar{\begingroup\catcode`\{=12\catcode`\}=12
     \texttt{\scantokens{#1}}\endgroup}}{}{}
\fi
```

---

A possible "definitive" solution that takes into account the suggestions in comments could be

```
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\margin@index#1{\marginpar{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}}
\ifdraft{}{\let\margin@index\@gobble}
\pretocmd{\@wrindex}{\margin@index{#1}}
\makeatother
```

The argument to the `\index` command will be written in the margin only when the documentclass option `draft` is specified.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make this depend to the "draft" documentclass option?

Comment: There’s also the [`ifdraft` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifdraft) which makes it maybe easier (i.e. more readable) to test if one is in draft mode or not.

Comment: @egreg: The `\ifdraft` syntax is not `\ifdraft` _then_ `\else` else `\fi` but `\ifdraft{` _then_ `}{` _else_ `}`

Comment: @egreg: BTW: Why not `\marginpar{\begingroup\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\endgroup}`?

Comment: @egreg: In a short test `\pretocmd` at the argument of `\ifdraft` seems to fail every time. It even seems to fail at the first argument of `\@firstoftwo`. So you have go back to `\if@draft ... \fi`. Sorry.

Comment: @Schweinebacke It's a good idea: `\marginpar{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}`

Comment: This produces *no* index marks whatsoever for me with documentclass `memoir`. Can it be made to work with memoir?

Comment: @murray Probably so, but some more details are needed: `memoir` changes several things connected to index production. Please, open a new question.

Comment: @egreg: See new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493407/mark-index-entries-in-text-itself-like-showkeys-with-memoir-documentclass.