# Mark indexed entries in the text itself?

Tags: indexing

I will be working with a professional indexer of the old school — meaning that she prefers making her index on cards using a pencil while looking at a finished book whose pagination will not change — and am searching for tools that will lessen the stress involved for both of us. Neither index cards nor static pagination are a viable option in the present case.

Are there any tools that would enable me to show exactly what words have been indexed in a given line in some unobtrusive way — say by underlining or shading them in the text?

I am aware of the `\showidx` package, which is useful. Its weakness in my situation is that it takes the whole page as its domain of operation, which it not easy for the indexer to follow; I'm looking for something that actually marks the indexed text, or at least makes `\showidx`-like margin notations on the same line as the indexed text.

Comment: I usually mark important and thus indexed terms with `\emph`. I'd suggest also putting a little symbol into the margin. So you could end up with `\newcommand[1]{\index{#1}\emph{#1}\marginpar{\small IDX}}`.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32234/visualize-index-entries-in-the-text

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm just throwing this idea out there; not sure whether it might be of help. It is somewhat inspired by David's [`showkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeindex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@theindexentry}[1]{%
  \smash{%
    \rlap{\rule{.4pt}{.8\baselineskip}}% Vertical rule
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}\tiny\ttfamily#1\end{lrbox}% Box index entry
    \rlap{\raisebox{.6\baselineskip}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}}% key
  }%
}
\def\@wrindex#1{%
  \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
    {\string\indexentry{#1}{\thepage}}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack%
  \@theindexentry{#1}%
}
\def\@index#1{\endgroup\@esphack\@theindexentry{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Lorem\index{Alpha} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\index{alpha} adipiscing elit. 
Proin ullamcorper\index{gnat} quam magna, quis convallis\index{gnus!good} sapien. Donec 
at ligula vel dolor varius\index{bites!vegetable} lobortis id ut orci\index{gnat!size of}. Maecenas 
commodo fringilla elit\index{Alphabet}, et pellentesque purus ornare vitae. 
Aenean non metus ipsum. Lorem\index{gnat!anatomy} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing\index{alphas} elit. Ut mauris lorem, accumsan a sagittis ut, 
rutrum fringilla arcu. Cras ullamcorper faucibus\index{alpha bet} quam id molestie.

Nunc et\index{alphabet} sem et turpis semper adipiscing et id nibh. In nibh 
mauris, placerat sed consequat placerat, dignissim ut\index{at!bat|see {bat, at}} arcu. 
Aenean eleifend justo volutpat lectus\index{gnus!bad} interdum pellentesque. 
Etiam cursus varius\index{twenty@xx} tellus, non pretium nibh tempus sit amet. 
Suspendisse sed mauris nisl. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et 
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur\index{alpha@$\alpha$} ridiculus mus. Nullam 
at feugiat nisi\index{bites!animal!gnats}.
\end{document}
```

It prints, for every `\index`, a vertical rule showing the point of reference, as well as the key used (minus `{` or `}`, for simplicity) in `\tiny\ttfamily`. Using [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) one could make the appearance less intrusive by printing in `black!30` (say):

[image]

`\@theindexentry` prints the index-related content. `\smash` takes care of any vertical adjustment, while the entire index entry is set inside a zero-width `\rlap` to remove any horizontal adjustment.

The definition of `\@wrindex` (in the presence of `\makeindex`) and `\@index` was taken directly from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx).

Comment: More than exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: Small problem with this solution is that it [adds extra vertical space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135290/why-does-smash-screw-up-vertical-spacing-after-tabulars), if `\index` occurs right after headings and some environments. e.g. `quote`. To avoid this it helps to put `\hspace{0pt}` right before `\smash`.

Comment: This method does not work with documentclass `memoir`: from the first invocation of `index{` in the body of the document, it gives error `Extra \endgroup` with details `\@index #1->endgroup`, a line feed, and `\@esphack \@theindexentry {@1}`. Is there a fix that will allow it to work with `memoir`, too?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but for future reference, I had success with the following using `imakeidx`.

```
\newcommand{\@theindexentry}[1]{%
  \smash{%
    \rlap{\rule{.4pt}{.8\baselineskip}}% Vertical rule
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}\tiny\ttfamily#1\end{lrbox}% Box index entry
    \rlap{\raisebox{.6\baselineskip}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}}% key
  }%
}

\renewcommand\imki@wrindexentrysplit[3]{%
  \expandafter\protected@write\csname#1@idxfile\endcsname{}%
    {\string\indexentry{#2}{#3}}%
    \@theindexentry{#1}%
}
```

The @theindexentry is taken directly from Werner's post.

Comment: If you are using more than one index, change the last line accordingly, e.g. to `\@theindexentry{#1: #2}%`