# Why does \smash screw up vertical spacing after tabulars?

Tags: tables, spacing, boxes

Using `\smash` after a tabular seems too screw up vertical spacing. Wheras
after a paragraph vertical spacing is fine. Witness for yourself:

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll}%
  One\cr
  Two\cr
\end{tabular}

\smash{Three}
```

[image: TeX output]

```
\noindent
One\\
Two

\smash{Three}
```

[image: TeX output]

Why is that so? What is TeX doing in each case?

Comment: Interestingly, the `\smash` bypasses the `\par` logic.  In both cases, there is no `\par` indent.  Put a `\strut` before either `\smash` and the indent comes back.  Strange.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes True, and there is no `\parskip` either.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\smash` workings end with `\box0` after a series of assignments which never change the mode (of course, restricted horizontal mode is entered when setting `\box0`, but this is irrelevant). So if `\smash` is issued in vertical mode, it doesn't cause TeX to switch to horizontal mode. The only box related commands that force horizontal mode are `\unhbox` and `\unhcopy`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, never use `\cr` in `tabular`, but always `\\`.

Now to the problem.

1. A `tabular`, by default is as high as deep. Height is the vertical amount by which a box sticks above the baseline, depth the same, but below the baseline.
2. `\noindent\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}<blank line>` makes a one line paragraph, that is packaged in a box put on the main vertical list.
3. `\smash` doesn't start a paragraph and, indeed, you don't get an indent because the box is placed directly in the vertical list.
4. Between boxes, TeX puts interline glue so that baselines are `\baselineskip` apart, unless this would make boxes overlap, based on the depth of the top box and the height of the bottom box. If

   ```
   \baselineskip-<depth of top box>-<height of bottom box> < \lineskiplimit
   ```

   TeX inserts `\lineskip` glue instead.
5. The bottom box has zero height, because it was smashed.
6. The computation makes TeX think that no overlap happens

Result: overlap.

This is more evident if you add two rows to the `tabular` and "show" the boxes. To understand the effect, you need to remember that a `tabular` extends below the baseline of the last row, because each row has a `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\fboxrule=0.1pt % hair rule
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule % don't add to the box dimensions
\newcommand{\showbaseline}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\leaders\hrule\hskip3cm}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\showbaseline
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
One\\
Two
\end{tabular}}

\smash{\showbaseline\fbox{Three}}

\noindent\showbaseline
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
One\\
Two\\
Three\\
Four
\end{tabular}}

\smash{\showbaseline\fbox{Five}}
\end{document}
```

In the first example you see that the baselines are exactly 12pt apart, while in the second the bottom of the `tabular` is 1pt from the second baseline because TeX, in this case, inserted the `\lineskip` glue.

[image]