# Mark index entries in text itself, like showkeys, with memoir documentclass

Tags: memoir, indexing, makeindex, showkeys

This question is just like that of [Mark indexed entries in the text itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/mark-indexed-entries-in-the-text-itself), except **for use with the `memoir` document class**.

How can index entries be marked within the text adjacent to where the `\index` command is placed — and *not* in the corner of the page as `showidx` does it, either:

- above the line, the way `showkeys` does it; and/or
- in the margin on the line where the `\index` appears?

Ideally, the user should have control over the format (font family, size, and color) of the entries that appear.

The answer at the cited question does not work with `memoir`.

A solution needs to work with:

1. `hyperref` (and Heiko Oberdiek's "quick and dirty fix to allow `showidx` and `hyperref` to coexist).
2. Multiple indexes, e.g. he main one and an index of names (where one uses `\index[names]{..}`).

Here's a sample source file, albeit with only a single index:

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}    
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\makeindex

\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=red,linkcolor=blue}

%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{We begin}\index{beginning}

Hello\index{greeting!hello|(}% 
\index{Hello}  %
to the World!\index{World}
\index{greeting|seealso{Hello,World}}  

\newpage
abc\index{abc}%
\index{alphabet|see{abc}} %
is before def.\index{greeting!hello|)}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And here's an accompanying `.ist` file:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\medskip\\hfill\\large\\textsf{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\hfill}\\medskip\\nopagebreak\n"
```

Comment: I think that you are asking for a change to `memoir`. I have looked at my original code but through fading capabilities I can't understand it. Perhaps the current maintainer could help.

Comment: @PeterWilson: Thank you for doing that much! I was hoping there could be a simple patch the user could include in a preamble, given that (1) `memoir` emulates `showidx`, and (2) the answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/mark-indexed-entries-in-the-text-itself does what I want if one is using `showidx` itself (with `book` or `article` documentclass).